# android mediarecorder.start fails in tablet

Tags: android

i have developed  an app for tablets which uses front camera for vedio recording,i tested that app on samsung galaxy s (android 2.3.6)and it works well but when i ran the same code on htc flyer(android 2.3.4) it get stuck when ever mediarecorder.start() executes.what could be the reason :)

```
    public boolean startRecording() throws IOException{
        try {
            camera.unlock();
            //mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(maxDurationInMs);
            File externalStorage = Environment.getRootDirectory();

            File r=getDir("jaris", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), r.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            File tempFile = new File(r.getAbsolutePath(),"kkcadsga.3gp");
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());

            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFramesPerSecond);

            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());

            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
           // mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            //mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file stored1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //camera.unlock();
                       try{
                           mediaRecorder.prepare();
                       }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status  "+ e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file stored4444  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View save) {
                                //camera.lock();

                            try{    mediaRecorder.start();

                            }catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                                b1.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                                b2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sto ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            });

//          for(int k=0; k < 4000 ; k++){
//              for(int n=0; k < 4000 ; k++){
//                  
//              }
//          }
            OnClickListener i = null;
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){



                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.reset();
                    camera.lock();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stopped ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    b2.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                    b1.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                }
                    });



return true;



    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    }
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output?